# Which organism is this?

Tags: species-identification

Place: Bangalore, India

Month: September, 2015

Current weather: Cloudy and rainy

Google images search was just giving me dragonfly photos. That organism is on grass blade.

[image]

Image is captured by me.

Comment: Certainly not a dragonfly. This looks like a grasshopper but I can't tell the species.

Comment: I doubt it is grasshopper. Few of my friends suggested it is some kind of grass insect which uses it's wing to camouflage.

Answer (score 4):

This is an insect in the order Neuroptera, definitely neither a dragonfly (order Odonata) nor a grasshopper (Order Orthoptera).  The name of that order means "nerve-wing", which referes to the intricate network of veins throughout the wings, which have a very different appearance and pattern than the wings of either dragonflies or grasshoppers.  I'm not familiar with Indian fauna per se, but the long antennae with slightly curved/hooked tips make it look more like an antlion (family Myrmeleontidae within the Neuroptera) than an owlfly (family Ascalaphidae within the Neuroptera; their antennae have small clubs at the ends), though it's a bit hard to tell from the photo.

Comment: I also think that an antlion is likely. Either way, the front legs and antenna seems to be directed forward along the leaf/overlaid, which makes the antenna look a bit weird.